# How to add Lucene filter as dynamic conditions?

Tags: filter, lucene

First of all, I know title of my question is ambiguous, but I don't know how to say. You'll know when you see my example.

In SQL queries, you can apply dynamic conditions with '1=1'.

Let me give example.

```
select * from PROD.EMPLY
WHERE 1=1
AND ( NAME = 'JOHN' OR NAME = 'MARY' OR NAME = 'KEVIN') ;
```

As above, I want to apply filters like below.

```
BooleanFilter BF = new BooleanFilter();
TermsFilter tf1 = new TermsFilter();
TermsFilter tf2 = new TermsFilter();

//tf1 => 1=1

//tf2 => name condition
tf2.addTerm("name", "JOHN");
tf2.addTerm("name", "MARY");
tf2.addTerm("name", "KEVIN");

BF.add(new FilterClause(tf1, Occur.MUST)); // 1=1 condition
BF.add(new FilterClause(tf2, Occur.MUST)); // name condition
```

But the results aren't matched as I expected.(no hits)

As I know, it's because there's no null/empty search method in Lucene.
I also checked whether I can switch BooleanFilter/TermsFilter with [MatchAllDocsQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html).

However in my case, my Lucene version is so old(2.3.2) that there's no MatchAllDocsQuery in my version, and I don't want filter's conditions to affect to lucene's scoring.

I searched within stackoverflow and google, but there's no case which matches my situation.

Any help would be very appreciated and thanks for reading.

Comment: That is indeed pretty old, had to download the source to check, but there *is*, in fact, a `MatchAllDocsQuery` in 2.3.2.

Comment: @femtoRgon Thank you for comment. Thanks to your comment, I found there is MatchAllDocsQuery. But, if possible, I want to use filter rather than using MatchAllDocsQuery, because Query affects Lucene's scoring, while filter doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to answer myself, but I hope that my poor solution may help/inspire someone who have same trouble.

In my case, as above, my Lucene version is so lower version that many filters are restricted.
However, I didn't want to use query, because I didn't want filters to affect to scoring.

So, I cleared myself by "manual" filter.
My development language was Java, so I used contains method.

To brief my solution, like below.

1. Search Lucene with AS-IS method.
2. Within result, compare with contains method (I added this step.)

example :

```
if (result.contains("KEVIN") ) {
 isFilteredResult = true;
} else if (result.contains("JOHN") ) {
 isFilteredResult = true;
}
...
```

3. The only results which contains condition keywords are displayed.

I was worried about this solution because this way is done with not Lucene but Java step. So, I guessed so much memory would be consumed.
However, the perfomance isn't bad as I was worried, and the users are satisfied with both performance and results.

I know this solution isn't good way, but if the condition is so restricted, this way would also a solution.

Thanks for reading.
And if there's better solution, please let me know.